# how to update Large tree map without redrawing chart?

Tags: highcharts

I have a `highchart` tree map with 2 level that is for showing the price of stock market and the value of each part change almost every seconds and I want update the each part value but as I see in highchart we can update chart by change data and redraw chart and this cause to chart go back to first level.
how can update value of each part of second level without redrawing chart?

here is a jsfiddle link when click on area at first level go to second level and then when click the button update and go back to first level but I want to update on second level 
http://jsfiddle.net/1e6yay4t/

Comment: Always when you would like to "update" point, you need to render parts of chart. It is related with required destroy SVG elements and create new one. Please isolate your example on jsfiddle.net and then we verify if any optimization is possible.

Answer (score 5):

A JSFiddle would be better as we could see exactly your problem. If you don't want to see the chart redrawn after each update, the `update()` method of Highcharts as a boolean argument which exists especially for that. See [this documentation](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Series.update).

You may need to use :

```
chart.series[0].update({...}, false);
```

Comment: In that case, elements are not updated, so you don't observe a changes in charts.

Comment: @SebastianBochan Without the fiddle it was difficult to understand what OP wanted. Don't you think he should use the drilldown module instead of manually define his treemap levels ?

Answer (score 3):

I modified your code slightly so that I could see what was going on.  But, in order to stay on the 2nd level when you update, update the point instead of the entire series.

```
$("#update-map").on('click', function () {
    tag[3].value += 30000000;
    var chart = $('#treemap').highcharts();
    chart.series[0].data[3].update(tag[3]);
})
```

http://jsfiddle.net/1e6yay4t/1/

(this will work with any point, I just picked 3 because the values in that group are closer, so it's more apparent what is happening)